# Can't get the JSON data from openweathermap API to my flutter app

Tags: flutter, openweathermap

Whereas it totally works when I do it with curl like this:

```
curl 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={41.01}&lon={28.97}&appid={my_secret_api_key}'
```

Openweathermap is free you can try it yourself, remember to verify email otherwise it won't work.
And this is my app in flutter. Ignore the album classes, I didn't change them according to the data sent back yet because I need to fix this issue first, json doesn't come at all.

Just check the response.body variable, it gives 401 error. This is problematic. Turning json into the flutter data is not a big problem for me:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={41.01}&lon={28.97}&appid=${HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader}'),
    // Send authorization headers to the backend.
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: '666319c58bc57caab32599c61b82c50e',
    },
  );
  print('response body: ${response.body}');
  final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

  return Album.fromJson(responseJson);
}


void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//IGNORE THESE PLEASE, NOT IMPORTANT YET. SO I MOVED THEM HERE.
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  const Album({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 401 error means you are not authorized to access the data. Are you sure your api key is OK?

Comment: Yes it's ok. As I said, using curl instead returns a lot of data, it returns a place called Karaköy. It works. But not in flutter :(

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure that "${HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader}" in your string interpolation is correct. When you set the key directly in the string and removing your header, does it work?

Comment: Ok I removed the curly braces from that line and it works now. Thanks. Like this:
   https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=41.01&lon=28.97&appid=my_secret_api_key

Comment: One more question, can I only take the parts of JSON inside and leave the rest? I don't need wind data etc. for example.

Comment: Yes you can, juste create a new object with only the values you want from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, remove the header of your request and use the interpolation without it.

```
String myKey = 'myKey';
Uri.parse(
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={41.01}&lon={28.97}&appid=$myKey'),
)
```